# TClientSocket in a console app causes linker errors

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have a console application that i got to make and i would like to use `TClientSocket`/`TServerSocket` in it.

The problem is that when i am trying to compile it, i am getting a linker error regarding the constructors and the destructors of the `TBaseSocket` and `TCustomSocket` classes (`TClientSocket` inherits from those two i think).

The linker error is something like this

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to ~TCustomSocket
```

The thing is that in a VCL Form project it compiles just fine, so i guess i am not including some libs paths that the form projects includes by default.

So if anyone could help me i would be grateful.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: When you created the console project, did you make sure that "uses VCL" was checked? It's not possible to change that after the project is created

Comment: Add a TDataModule to the project, drop a TClientSocket or TServerSocket on it, save the project, then remove the TDataModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with Builder XE. Add 'inet.bpi' to your Requires list and it should link.